# What's the distinction between the roles of the .NET framework and "Visual Basic" compiler?

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-construction, clr

It was my understanding that the .NET framework essentially provided all of the built-in functionality (classes, methods, etc.) that is available when programming a VB.NET application. After all, that's why it's called the "framework".

However, I've recently learned that, apparently, some functionalities are provided by something else: the compiler. What led me to this discovery was trying to use these two VB.NET features: [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) and the [NameOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/nameof) operator. I was trying to use these in a third-party VB.NET IDE (not Visual Studio), but I was getting compiler errors. After reading the documentation, both of those features say they are "available in Visual Basic 14 and later".

It took a good bit of digging around for me to figure out that "Visual Basic", in this context, means the *compiler*, not the programming language. (Could they maybe have named it something less ambiguous?). This was a new revelation for me. I had always thought that the .NET framework version, and that alone, determined what out-of-the-box functionality was available to me. I had no idea there was such a thing as the "compiler version" that affected these things as well.

That said, I guess my question is this: why are there functionalities, like string interpolation and NameOf, that are part of the compiler, rather than the .NET framework? I would have thought that the distinction between the framework and the compiler was that the framework provided functionality, while the compiler simply converted the source code to IL code. Why is that distinction blurred in these instances?

Comment: the compiler can provide language features, e.g. syntax, keywords etc. The compiler interprets the VB.NET code you wrote and check if it's valid. So if you have a version of the compiler which doesn't support, for example, interpolated strings, then it won't consider that code to be valid, and so it won't compile it. It would make no sense for that to be a framework-level feature because the framework supports multiple programming languages, but the syntax is specific to the individual programming language. C# syntax is totally different, but it's still a .NET language.

Comment: The .NET Framework version does also have part to play, in the sense that you set a target version of the framework for the compiler to work with, and it compiles the code to bytecode which will execute against that framework. The framework then provides compatibility with the host operating system. The rest of such as classes, methods etc are actually provided by code libraries - some come installed by default when you install the framework, and of course you can add more of those by downloading Nuget packages - or writing your own! They're not _directly_ part of the framework...

Comment: ...but the ones installed by default tend to be things which are crucial to the useful operation of a modern programming environment, such as ability to make certain system calls efficiently, such as disk I/O, basic string manipulation, that kind of thing. The great thing about those libraries is that, once they're compiled to IL/bytecode, it doesn't matter what language they were written in originally - the compiler converted it to something language-independent. So you can then use those compiled libraries from any .NET language.

Comment: P.S. "the framework provided functionality, while the compiler simply converted the source code to IL code". Yes that's more or less it (although much of the functionality is actually provided by libraries rather than the core framework). So then why are you confused? Maybe you think interpolated strings is "functionality" rather than "convenient syntax"? (For example, if you create a string via interpolation, or via normal concatenation, the result will still be an operation to create a string, and will likely be compiled into identical bytecode in each case).So it's form rather than function

Comment: `why are there functionalities, like string interpolation and NameOf, that are part of the compiler, rather than the .NET framework` - because these features require access to the *source code text*, and only the compiler has that access. Same applies to constructs like `If` and `While`, which, I believe, you did not see as "functionalities", but which are features of the same level. It would be technically possible to program in purely functional style (`Call Framework.If(condition, lambda_if_true, lambda_if_false)`), but you would *hate* that, and it would be *massively* inefficient.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here over exactly the meaning of "the .NET Framework."  The .NET environment includes three different things: the class library (in the F1 help, this is the material under ".NET API Reference" and note that it is not identical for ".NET Core" vs. ".NET Framework" vs. ".NET Standard"), the common language runtime, and the language compilers.

Comment: The class library can be called from any language without any special language features.  The CLR provides the fundamental .NET behavior (GC, IL, COM interop, etc) which provide the foundation for any language written in .NET, although if you were really masochistic you could write directly in IL and use ilasm to turn it into a program (in that sense, the IL that would be compiled by ilasm relates to the CRL's operating language the same way assembly relates to machine-executable binary code).

Comment: The language compilers provide implementations of the various .NET languages.  They provide the language syntax and the parsers.  Conceptually, it's probably best to think of the language as being completely distinct from the class library (although I'm sure there are aspects of the various languages that compile down to class library calls e.g. the various `For Each ... Next` transformations).  The languages are somewhat constrained by the capabilities of the CLR, but even then, they can go their own ways e.g. I know C# has some things like `out` which don't really come from the CLR.

Comment: The various distributions of the .NET Framework will typically include all three of the items I noted above, and all of them change from one version to the next.  New things (namespaces, classes, properties, methods) are added to the class library, new capabilities are added to the CLR, new features are added to the languages.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c C# and VB.NET compilers were part of .NET Framework releases, but later became individual components. For most recent changes, you have to dig into discussions on GitHub, https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn